# Hackage のライブラリを高速にインストールする方法は？

Tags: haskell

Hackage からライブラリを cabal でインストールする際にコンパイル時間がかかります。例えば [wreq](http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/doc/wreq-0.1.0.0/html/) というライブラリをインストールしようとしたところ、依存するライブラリのインストールまで含めて、手元の環境では10分程度かかりました。

依存関係の衝突が怖いため cabal sandbox 内にインストールしています。

バイナリ配布など、ライブラリのインストールを高速化する手段はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cabalコマンドには[sandboxのパスを指定する機能](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#sandboxes-advanced-usage)があるので、あらかじめ依存関係が壊れない組み合わせであるとわかっていれば、複数のプロジェクトでsandboxを共有することでコンパイル時間を減らせます。

使えるパッケージやバージョンは限られてしまいますが、[Stackage](http://www.stackage.org/)を使えばStackageのリリースごとにsandboxを作り、プロジェクトごとに適切なsandboxを指定することで、依存関係を壊すこと無くビルド済みのパッケージを共有できると思います。

Answer (score 2):

`cabal install` には並列処理を行うオプションがあります。

```
-j --jobs[=NUM]  Run NUM jobs simultaneously.
```

確認はしていませんが、おそらくバックエンドで利用している make コマンドにそのまま渡されるオプションかと思われます。ただ、並列に処理を行っても問題のない部分(依存関係のない)のみで行われますので、どの程度高速化が図れるのかはインストールするパッケージ次第となりそうです。なお、既にご存知かもしれませんが、オプションに指定する数値 `NUM` はお使いのシステムの総コア数以下にしておくと良いかと思います。

その他、以下のオプションを指定すれば、あるいは時間の節約になるかもしれません。

```
--disable-tests
--disable-library-coverage
--disable-benchmarks
--disable-documentation
```

詳しくは `cabal install -h` をご覧ください。

Comment: -j オプションなしでも依存ライブラリレベルでは並列してビルドが走るようです。すでに CPU を使いきっている状態なので並列化による高速化は見込めなさそうです。--disable-foo は試してみます。

Comment: `~/.cabal/config`に`jobs: $ncpus`あるいは適切な並列度を指定している場合は`-j`オプションを指定しなくても並列に処理が行われます。

Comment: 私の環境では `~/.cabal/config` に `jobs: $ncpus` が指定されていました。 `~/.cabal/config` 手動で作成していないので、いずれかのタイミングで設定ファイルが生成されていたようです。